# Gerrit can not login

Tags: gerrit

I setup a gerrit server, and I can login as admin (admin/passwd).

Then I installed the [gerrit command line tools](https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/cmd-index.html) and create a new user with the [command](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/cmd-create-account.html)

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_watcher.pub | ssh -p 29418 review.example.com gerrit create-account --group "'some-group'" --http-password "'passwd'" --ssh-key - watcher
```

user `wathcer` created successfully, but I can not login as `wathcer` user. It notice "Invalid username or password." what do I miss?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention at the ["gerrit create-account" documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-create-account.html):

> Creates a new internal-only user account.
>
> If the account is created without an email address, it may only be
>   used for batch/role access, such as from an automated build system or
>   event monitoring over gerrit stream-events.

You can't log in, interactively, using this account.